# aclput on aix server

Tags: bash, aix

i have some problems with aclput on my aix server.

I have a file that contais filenames and their acls.

For example,

`/home/file1.txt`

```
attributes: SUID
base permissions:
   owner  (frank): rw-
   group (system): r-x
   others        : ---
extended permissions:
enabled
       permit    rw-    u:user1
       deny      r--    u:user2, g:group1
       permit    rw-    g:user3, g:group2
```

`/home/file2.txt`

```
attributes: SUID
base permissions:
   owner  (sasadm): rwx
   group (sasadm): rwx
   others        : ---
extended permissions:
enabled
       permit    rw-    u:user1
       deny      r--    u:user2, g:group1
       permit    rw-    g:user3, g:group2
```

How can i put acl for these file using aclput?

Answer (score 0):

```
aclput -i <Acl input file> <File Object>
```